# Does the difference between full and diff database size make sense?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have 2 backup jobs in sql server :

1. Full backup every Thursday -> size 1.5 TB
2. Differential backup every day at 8 -> size 12 GB

When the diff backup job runs for first time, there is a big difference in size, compared to the size of the full backup. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you see this? https://serverfault.com/questions/56610/database-backup-differential-file-size-question

Comment: It's less than 1% of the whole DB, doesn't sound much